# Creating a 3D road in Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

I'm trying to create a simple game in android. By road I meant games like `Temple Run` or `Subway Surf` but much simpler and abstract so I could do it only with the OpenGL ES without any other libraries.
So I've read a lot of basic tutorials that explains the 3D construction logic and used the basic sample of creating a 3D cube that rotates.

I am now trying to use that sample to create the game road. I made the square to look more like a rectangle and duplicate it to a 30x5 square road. I've tried many combinations and the internet to find a solution and yet I have this problems\questions:

1. How do I set all 30x5 squares to be one next to another? I'm always
   getting the squares with some unwanted gap
2. I want to set the vieweye point (the "camera") 45 degrees to the
   middle of the first row, so the player could see the road upon him
3. Next, I would want to move along the road. So Iv'e seen the rotate
   and how it works. Is there a way to do the same to the viewpoint or
   do I need to change the squares drawing Z's?
4. I see that onDrawFrame() is calling over and over many times. To
   control the FPS, I've seen on the internet that people have used
   there own FPS calculation with a sleep(). Isn't there a built one
   already?

GLRenderer code:

```
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.util.Log;


class GLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private static final String TAG = "GLRenderer" ;
    private final Context context;

    private float mCubeRotation = 70.0f;
    private Triangle triangle;
    private Cube[][] cube;


    GLRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f); 

        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);

        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL10.GL_NICEST);

    }
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        Log.d("MyOpenGLRenderer", "Surface changed. Width=" + width
                + " Height=" + height);
        System.out.println("arg");

        //get map
        cube = new Cube[30][5];
        for(int i = 0; i < cube.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < cube[i].length; j++)
                    cube[i][j] = new Cube();

        //draw triangle
        triangle = new Triangle(0.5f, 1, 0, 0);

        // Define the view frustum
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, ratio, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

    }
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        // Clear the screen to black
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 


        //translate(dx, dy, dz)

        // Position model so we can see it
        //gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mCubeRotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
        cube[0][0].draw(gl);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
        cube[0][1].draw(gl);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);
        cube[0][2].draw(gl);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();                                    

        //set rotation
        mCubeRotation -= 0.15f;
        System.out.println("mCubeRotation: "+mCubeRotation);

    }
}
```

Cube code:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

class Cube {

    private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;  //vertex
    private FloatBuffer mColorBuffer;   //color 
    private ByteBuffer  mIndexBuffer;   //face indices

    float width  = 1.0f;
    float height = 0.5f;
    float depth  = 1.0f;

    private float vertices[] = { 
                         -width, -height, -depth, // 0
                          width, -height, -depth, // 1
                          width,  height, -depth, // 2
                         -width,  height, -depth, // 3
                         -width, -height,  depth, // 4
                          width, -height,  depth, // 5
                          width,  height,  depth, // 6
                         -width,  height,  depth, // 7
    };

    private float colors[] = {
                               0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                               1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
                               0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
                               0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
                               1.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
                               1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                               0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
                               0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
                               0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
                               1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                               1.0f,  1.0f
                            };

    private byte indices[] = {
                              0, 4, 5,
                              0, 5, 1,
                              1, 5, 6,
                              1, 6, 2,
                              2, 6, 7,
                              2, 7, 3,
                              3, 7, 4,
                              3, 4, 0,
                              4, 7, 6,
                              4, 6, 5,
                              3, 0, 1,
                              3, 1, 2
                              };

    public Cube() {
            ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
            byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mVertexBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
            mVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
            mVertexBuffer.position(0);

            byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
            byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            mColorBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
            mColorBuffer.put(colors);
            mColorBuffer.position(0);

            mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
            mIndexBuffer.put(indices);
            mIndexBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {             
            gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mColorBuffer);

            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                            mIndexBuffer);

            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

Eventually I'll draw the square array using glDrawArrays() or glDrawElements() but for now I've used only 3 objects.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of questions here. I can't cover everything in detail, but hopefully I can give you some pointers to steer you in the right direction.

To draw 150 squares, you have a number of options:

1. Create a vertex buffer with a single square, and draw it 150 times, with translations applied. This is probably the easiest to get you off the ground, so I would recommend getting it working first. It's a reasonable approach if all your squares look the same.
2. Create 150 vertex buffers, with different coordinates. I wouldn't recommend it because it's the least efficient, and doesn't have any benefits over other approaches.
3. Store the vertices for all 150 squares in a single vertex buffer. This will be the most efficient of the first 3 options, but only works well as long as the relative orientation of the squares remains the same. You may want to try this once you have the basics working.
4. Use instanced rendering. This is a more advanced feature, and only available in ES 3.0. Just mentioning it for future reference.

What you attempted is sort of a hybrid between option 1 and 2. If you want to go for option 1, you only need one instance of your `Cube` class. If you look at what you did, this makes sense. You created 150 objects that are all exactly the same, which is not very useful.

Now, on your questions:

1. To draw the squares without gaps between them, the amount of your translations needs to be the same as the size of each square. Your squares are 2 units wide, but you translate each one by 10 units. You also translate them in the z-direction, which I don't quite understand.
2. If you want to stick with the kind of functionality you have been using, check out `GLU.gluLookAt()`. It allows you to place your camera where you want it, and point it in any direction.
3. Same as 2. Call `GLU.gluLookAt()` every time you want to move the viewpoint.
4. Android caps the frame rate at 60 frames per second. That's normally what you should be shooting for anyway, IMHO. If you want to limit it to 30 fps later to save power, I think you can cross that bridge when you get there. Based on what I researched recently, there's no clean and portable way to do this on Android. The proposed solutions I have seen all look kind of hacky to me.

A couple more things on your code:

- Your color definitions look odd. You specify colors in 4 components, and the size of the array is correct for that. But you write the array with 3 values per line, which makes it look like you want 3 component colors. Either one can be done, but you need to make sure that you're consistent. 3 components are enough, unless you need transparency.
- You are using ES 1.0. That's valid, and might be easier to get started with. But you should be aware that many of its features are considered obsolete, and using ES 2.0 would let you learn more modern and current OpenGL features. The initial hurdle will be higher, so there's definitely a tradeoff here.